# Set different margins for text and footnotes using book class

Tags: footnotes, margins, geometry, book-design, footmisc

I'm writing an user manual for an application I made, and I'm using the book documentclass, with the `geometry` and the `footmisc` package. What I need is to increase the margin for the footnotes so they won't take the full textwidth. A MWE (maybe not so minimal...) is as follows:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry} % ,showframe
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\makeatother
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{2.5mm}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/logo.png}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Company's shortname\par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Manual de Usuario \par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Company's name \par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape My name ;) \par}
    \today \par
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

%\include{./TeX_files/intro}
\mainmatter
%\include{./TeX_files/primeros_pasos}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_actas}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_fotos}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
Some filler text here... \footnote{This is the footnote.}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

My margins are 1.8cm on both sides, and I need them to be 3cm for footnotes.

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the margins in `\@makefntext`

[image]

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry} % ,showframe
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\advance\leftskip 1.2cm
\advance\rightskip 1.2cm
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\makeatother
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{2.5mm}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/logo.png}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Company's shortname\par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Manual de Usuario \par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Company's name \par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape My name ;) \par}
    \today \par
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

%\include{./TeX_files/intro}
\mainmatter
%\include{./TeX_files/primeros_pasos}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_actas}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_fotos}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
Some filler text here... \footnote{This is the footnote.}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

---

The above redefinition is for standard latex footnotes, for `footmisc` you can instead do

```
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{%
  \advance\leftskip 1.2cm
  \advance\rightskip 1.2cm
 }
```

to add the margins to footmisc's setup rather than redefine the latex command directly

Comment: Wow, thanks @David!! But there's an issue there... I'm using `[flushmargin]{footmisc}` to eliminate indenting on footnotes, but it's not working anymore... Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez quick look at footmisc sources suggests that you could instead do `\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\advance\leftskip 1.2cm
\advance\rightskip 1.2cm}` to add the margins to footmisc's setup rather than redefine the latex command directly

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez done:-)